# How to position footer when parent uses background-size:cover

Tags: html, css

I have a page whose body uses background-size:cover with an image. I want my footer to stay at the bottom of the page (not sticky; just at the bottom of the page). The problem is that the footer only stays at the bottom of the original image size so when the window is resized to larger than the original image size, the footer stays in place with a margin below it. I have tried any number of things with no success. Here is my html:

```
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <div class="contr"><div class="g01"></div></div>
        <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />
        <div style="clear: both;"></div>
        <div class= "footer"></div>
</form> 
</body>
```

and then my style rules:

```
body   
{
font-size: .80em;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", "Lucida Grande", "Segoe UI", Arial, Helvetica, Verdana, sans-serif;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
background: url(hex2.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.hex2.png', sizingMethod='scale');
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.AlphaImageLoader(src='.hex2.png', sizingMethod='scale')";
min-height:100%;
}

.footer 
{
width:94%;
height:123px;
background: url(lines.png); 
position: relative;
bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle that shows the issue you're having?

Comment: setting up the fiddle made me realize that what I thought I was doing to set my footer to the bottom was not actually putting it to the bottom of the body, just the bottom of the last element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented a footer in a page with `background-size: cover` in the body and didn't run into problems.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <h1>Lorem Ipsun</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    <p>Footer</p>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
html {
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url(image.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

#container {
    height: 100%;
}

#footer {
    background: orange;
    height: 100px;
    margin-top: -100px;
}
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/f68u5/2/)

Does this works for you?

Comment: Partially. It made me realize that I didn`t have anything set to "height=100%" inside the body. Now my footer goes exactly beneath my lowest element; now I just need to figure out how to set my layout so that the background does not go below my lowest element when I expand the screen